# Create a pie chart for different items with filter

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts, pivot-table

I need to create a pie chart for sold and not sold for 4 items. Items (pen, pencil, book, box) should be in filter. If I click any item my chart should show sold and not sold number.

[image: Need to create a pie chart]

data.csv:

```
Item,Sold,Not Sold
Pen,58,20
Pencil,26,28
Book,27,15
Box,19,17
```

Comment: put data in pivot table, create chart from pivot table

Comment: I am unable to create pie chart. Can you please create and share it to  saravanan.mamit@gmail.com

Comment: Kumar erm no not really, google how to do it, its not difficult